# How to effectively name a large amount of instances in python?

Tags: python, oop

I am doing OOP in python; I have a class called `mesh_grid`. I need to create a lot of objects. In some cases, I think as many as a million objects, or even more might be needed. Now I want to instantiate this and give the instances their name in a somehow automatic way, as shown in the codes below.

The question is, is using `vars()['some string']` the most efficient (computationally less intensive) way to do this? Are there any other better approaches?

```
class mesh_grid:
    num_mg = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.coord = ()             # Coordinates
        self.sol_conc = 0           # Solute concentration (physical quantity)
        mesh_grid.num_mg += 1

num_nodes = 20
for num in range(1,num_nodes+1):
    vars()['mg'+str(num)] = mesh_grid()
```

Comment: Do you really need *named* mass instantiating? After having these names object, it will not be effective to work with it. Maybe you need a name property within the class and then use dome container class that allows you indexed access.

Comment: Anytime you think you need to dynamically create variables/variable names, you're doing something wrong. Learn how to use collections like lists.

Comment: @PaulM. Thanks, nice point.

Comment: It's exactly what you are looking for. If you are not able to underrated it, look at @Wolf answer - maybe it will help to understand it. As an alternative to list, you may use a dict. As other already mentioned - when you decide to create variables dynamically - you are doing something wrong and should be using a data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are interested in creating a lot of objects of type `mesh_grid` and want to access/display it in a reasonable and effective was later on. Here for example is a list-based solution.

```
class mesh_grid:
    num_mg = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.coord = ()             # Coordinates
        self.sol_conc = 0           # Solute concentration (physical quantity)
        mesh_grid.num_mg += 1

nodes = []
for num in range(20):
    nodes.append(mesh_grid())
```

Mass access (for example output) is possible by

```
for node in nodes:
    print(node.coord, node.col_conc)
```

If `mesh_grid.num_mg` was meant to get the amount of nodes, this can effectively be done by the collection, `list` in the case shown above.

The following is an example without this class member, I also changed some names: the node class to `mesh_node` and the collection to `mesh_grid` because *it* represents the grid in this case (still implemented by a list). I also  allow to specify the member values by passing initialisers to `__init__`:

### Dense mesh

```
import random # simulate concentrations by random values

class mesh_node:
    def __init__(self, coord = (), sol_conc = 0):
        self.coord = coord
        self.sol_conc = sol_conc

width = 3
height = 3

mesh_grid = []
for i in range(width*height):
    mesh_grid.append(mesh_node((i % width, i // width), random.randint(1, 6)))
   
for node in mesh_grid:
    print(node.coord, node.sol_conc)
```

Here is an example output:

```
(0, 0) 2
(1, 0) 3
(2, 0) 5
(0, 1) 1
(1, 1) 3
(2, 1) 1
(0, 2) 6
(1, 2) 6
(2, 2) 4
```

### Sparse mesh

If you are implementing a *sparse mesh*, it may be better to switch to the `dict` container. Here you store only existing nodes by using `coord` as key and `sol_conc`as value:

```
import random

class MeshGrid:
    nodes = dict()
    def set_node(self, coord, sol_conc):
        self.nodes[coord] = sol_conc
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([f'{k} {v}' for k, v in self.nodes.items()])
    
width = 100
height = 100

grid = MeshGrid()
for i in range(width*height):
    # simulate that about 1/1000 nodes exist:
    if random.random() > 0.999:
       grid.set_node((i % width, i // width), random.randint(1, 6))
   
print(grid)
```

Here is the example output of a `100 x 100` grid with nodes in 11 out of 10.000 potential places:

```
(5, 11) 2
(17, 27) 6
(95, 29) 6
(49, 41) 4
(96, 45) 3
(87, 47) 1
(17, 52) 6
(23, 61) 5
(54, 68) 6
(73, 79) 1
(11, 93) 3
```

Comment: @Wolf Thank you very much for this detailed answer! I can get the point now, and your idea and suggestion would help me avoid getting stuck in the awkward situation of having problem with naming those instances. I didn´t realize that I can instantiate something without allocating a name or a label from object to object.